# Passing a default Integer value to a WCF service in Biztalk

Tags: wcf, biztalk, default-value

I have consumed WCF service in biztalk through "Add generated items". There is a method in WCF which takes an integer parameter. In orchestration I want to pass that method a default value or say I want to hard code input value. How I can achieve this. I have googled this question but didn't get any adequate result.

What I have done is declared an integer variable assign it a value, then I assigned that variable to a message of Integer type.

Now how I can assign this message to WebService Request type message? 
or how I can transform integer type message to WebService Request type message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Biztalk Scheduler Adapter is really helpful in this case. It generates desired XML on predefined scheduled set by the user. So fill up your XML with hard coded values and receive them through this adapter.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways to do this:

1. If you are mapping the request from another message, you can hard code it in the map - click on the field in the RHS of the Map Editor and set the hard coded value in the `Value` in the Property box
2. After creating a (dummy) request message, you can set the value using `xpath()` in an <del>expression</del> message *assignment* shape

   `xpath(myRequestMessage, "//*[local-name()='NameOfFieldHere']") = 3;  // Or set to it your variable`
3. If the field is distinguished in your schema, you can use the distinguished field instead of xpath, viz in an <del>expression</del> message assignment shape:

   `myRequestMessage.NameOfFieldHere = 3;`

(And note if its a multipart message, then it will be `myRequestMessage.Part.NameOfFieldHere` OFC)

One disclaimer: I've assumed the WCF service request message is trivial, i.e. just a single integer field. If your message is large, using `//local-name() ...` isn't recommended, since

1. There may be more than one node with with the name `NameOfFieldHere`
2. The XSL parser used by BizTalk is slow and resource intensive when evaluating large xml documents with `//`

Comment: dear thanks for reply. Unfortunately I was not able to implement your solutions. Actually I am new to Biztalk. The service reference added Multipart message types of Input and Output of every method(All with single body part). What I want just to pass a default value to a method. Please please guide me through simplest example. Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps this helps : BizTalk sees everything internally as a 'message', even a simple call to a web service which takes a single integer value. BizTalk imports both the request (BTS => WS) and the response (WS => BTS) as separate request / response messages as you've noted above. However, the request message needs to be initialized and assigned before it can be 'sent' to the web service.

Comment: dear Stuart I have tried all your schemes but couldn't succeeded. As I have told you that I am using Biztalk since one and half months. If you please please make just a little example for me. I am facing a great trouble. Please please...